# How to print every server using my bot with their members. discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to print in a chat all the servers using my bot with their users count.
Code I tried:

```
@bot.command()
async def list(ctx):
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        print(f"{guild.name} with {guild.users}")
```

guild.name works and guild.users doesn't. How to fix?
error: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'users'

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the following:

```py
f"{guild.member_count}"
```

Your **full code** could/would be:

```py
@bot.command()
async def list(ctx):
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        print(f"{guild.name} with {guild.member_count}")
```

- Make sure to turn Intents on, if you have not

*Also have a look at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild%20member_count#discord.Guild.member_count) for more information.*